# s.tk/realtime redirects to a non-existing page

Tags: feature-request, s.tk, realtime-questions

http://s.tk/realtime currently redirects to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/realtime/new-questions, which doesn't exist.

Please change the redirection to the real-time live updates at https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime

Adding a synonym or two such as http://s.tk/live-updates or http://s.tk/live would be nice — I can never remember the URL and it isn't prominently linked.